# Google Maps API Sometimes Not Showing Markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps to display a map with a set of markers on it. The code for the page (slightly simplified) is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer_compiled.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/infobox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/downloadxml.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
var gmarkers = [];

// global "map" variable
var map = null;
var markerCluster = null;

var hotelimage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('../images/hotel_icon.gif',
    new google.maps.Size(32, 37),
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    new google.maps.Point(16, 35));
var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('../images/hotel_shadow.png',
    new google.maps.Size(51, 37),
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    new google.maps.Point(16, 35));

// InfoBox
var boxText = document.createElement("div");
boxText.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid #4d6eb0; margin-top: 8px; background: white; padding: 5px;";

var ibOptions = {
    content: boxText,
    closeBoxURL: "",
    disableAutoPan: false,
    enableEventPropagation: true,
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(15, -50),
    boxStyle: {
        width: "240px",
        height: "100px"
    }
};

// global "infobox" variable
var ib = new InfoBox(ibOptions);

////////////////////////
// A function to create the markers and set up the event window function 
function createMarker(latlng, html, summary, photo1, photo2) {
    //    var contentString = html + "<br><span class='verdana'>" + summary + "</span>";
    var contentString = "<div style='min-height:75px'>" + photo1 + "<img src='/images/" + photo2 + "' width='105' height='75' align='left' style='margin-right:8px;border:none'></a>" + html + "<br><div class='verdana'>" + summary + "</div></div>";

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: latlng,
        icon: hotelimage,
        shadow: shadow,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {
        boxText.innerHTML = contentString;
        ib.open(map, marker);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function () {
        ib.close(map, marker);
    });
    gmarkers.push(marker);
}

function initialize() {
    var lat = 0;
    var lng = 0;
    var zoom = 0;
    var hotelname = 0;
    var query = location.search.substring(1);
    var pairs = query.split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
        var pos = pairs[i].indexOf("=");
        var argname = pairs[i].substring(0, pos).toLowerCase();
        var value = pairs[i].substring(pos + 1);
        if (argname == "lat") {
            lat = parseFloat(value);
        }
        if (argname == "lng") {
            lng = parseFloat(value);
        }
        if (argname == "zoom") {
            zoom = parseInt(value);
        }
        if (argname == "hotel") {
            hotelname = unescape(value);
        }
    }
    var thisLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var myOptions = {
        center: thisLatlng,
        zoom: zoom,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        streetViewControl: false,
        scaleControl: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
        }
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);

    ////////////////////

    downloadUrl("php-to-xml.php", function (doc) {
        var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);
        var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

            var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
            var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            var html = markers[i].getAttribute("html");
            var summary = markers[i].getAttribute("summary");
            var photo1 = markers[i].getAttribute("photo1");
            var photo2 = markers[i].getAttribute("photo2");

            var marker = createMarker(point, html, summary, photo1, photo2);
        }

        var clusterStyles = [{
            opt_textColor: '#5a7aba',
            url: '../images/cluster_icon.png',
            height: 40,
            width: 40
        }];

        var mcOptions = {
            gridSize: 35,
            maxZoom: 10,
            styles: clusterStyles
        };
        markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, gmarkers, mcOptions);
    });
}

//]]>
</script> 
</head> 

<body onload="initialize()"> 
<div id="content">
<h1>Little Hotels Map Search</h1>
<span class="verdana"><br /></span>
<table border=1 bordercolor="#666666">
      <tr>
        <td>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 640px; height: 450px"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
<br />
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

The points for placing the markers are obtained using the php-to-xml.php file which gets the data with a mySQL query and then presents it in XML form.

Sometimes it works perfectly, and sometimes it shows the map with no markers at all. As far as I know, it never shows just some markers.

I am working on the hypothesis that sometimes php-to-xml.php is slow to do it's job and then the map page is completed without the markers. I have experimented by changing

```
  downloadUrl("php-to-xml.php", function(doc) {
```

to

```
  downloadUrl("somethingelse.php", function(doc) {
```

in order to disable it. The map then shows without the markers, as I would expect.

This is very difficult to test as the page works right or wrong apparently randomly. Is there a way that I can ensure php-to-xml.php has finished before anything else happens?

EDIT

The downloadxml.js file referenced in the  is a file I downloaded from somewhere. It's completely "blackbox" to me.

```
/**
* Returns an XMLHttp instance to use for asynchronous
* downloading. This method will never throw an exception, but will
* return NULL if the browser does not support XmlHttp for any reason.
* @return {XMLHttpRequest|Null}
*/
function createXmlHttpRequest() {
 try {
   if (typeof ActiveXObject != 'undefined') {
     return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
   } else if (window["XMLHttpRequest"]) {
     return new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
 } catch (e) {
   changeStatus(e);
 }
 return null;
};

/**
* This functions wraps XMLHttpRequest open/send function.
* It lets you specify a URL and will call the callback if
* it gets a status code of 200.
* @param {String} url The URL to retrieve
* @param {Function} callback The function to call once retrieved.
*/
function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
 var status = -1;
 var request = createXmlHttpRequest();
 if (!request) {
   return false;
 }

 request.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (request.readyState == 4) {
     try {
       status = request.status;
     } catch (e) {
       // Usually indicates request timed out in FF.
     }
     if ((status == 200) || (status == 0)) {
       callback(request.responseText, request.status);
       request.onreadystatechange = function() {};
     }
   }
 }
 request.open('GET', url, true);
 try {
   request.send(null);
 } catch (e) {
   changeStatus(e);
 }
};

/**
 * Parses the given XML string and returns the parsed document in a
 * DOM data structure. This function will return an empty DOM node if
 * XML parsing is not supported in this browser.
 * @param {string} str XML string.
 * @return {Element|Document} DOM.
 */
function xmlParse(str) {
  if (typeof ActiveXObject != 'undefined' && typeof GetObject != 'undefined') {
    var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
    doc.loadXML(str);
    return doc;
  }

  if (typeof DOMParser != 'undefined') {
    return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
  }

  return createElement('div', null);
}

/**
 * Appends a JavaScript file to the page.
 * @param {string} url
 */
function downloadScript(url) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = url;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: The MarkerImage class is deprecated, use google.maps.Icon instead

Comment: This line doesn't make sense: `var marker = createMarker(point, html, summary, photo1, photo2);` your createMarker function doesn't return anything, so the `marker` variable in this context is null.  You may as well just do `createMarker(point, html, summary, photo1, photo2);`

Comment: When you remove the MarkerClusterer....do you see any difference?

Comment: Check the JavaScript console for errors.

Comment: @duncan, those are good points to tidy up my code, but I don't think they affect my main problem. I've done the changes you suggested and the page is working OK. But as the problem occurs at random, I haven't proved that it has solved anything.

Comment: @Dr.Molle. I have another similar page that doesn't use Clusterer and that exhibits the same problem.

Comment: what does your downloadUrl function look like?